# How to store hyperlink in asp.net/c# datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Any way to do this? I need standard link:

> [Stack Owerflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I tryed hyperlink and url datatypes, and it won't accept this format.

I need to display it in aspxgridview as column with links.

I tryed storing html tag as string, and it doesnt work in aspxgridview.

```
T1.Columns.Add("edit", typeof(Hyperlink));

        for (int i = 0; i < T1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            T1.Rows[i][6]  = 
                "<a href=\"~/editprofile.aspx?id=" + T1.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "\" >Edit</a>";

        }
```

There's code, basically, Im calling edit page, passing id of user.

Comment: What did you try (code/data) what failed? Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Show us your code. You should read [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried with [GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataHyperLinkColumntopic)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did at the end, manually added column to ASPxGridView as Hyperlink column, and added raw links do datatable. Thanks Filip!

Answer (score 2):

You don't store the hyperlink, you store the hyperlink's href value, e.g. the raw URL.

To display in a `GridView Column`, just use the `<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>` control rather than a Bound Template, e.g.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <a href='<%#Eval("LinkText")%>'><%#Eval("LinkName")%></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```